# Are multiple navigation menus really better?

Tags: navigation, design-patterns, interface, information-architecture, human-interface-guideline

I like the interface design a Lyric a lot. It's designed mobile/tablet first, and has a lot of big, clear buttons that make navigation easy.

However, one thing that I've been wondering about is how they have two primary navigation menus on all pages. This does break up the total number of list options, but still, I count 14 different menu items in both the black & white menus. That's way more than 7+/-2 rule, and I'm wondering if there is a pattern or best practice describes this.

If anyone has any evidence-based UX research on this, that would be incredibly helpful also.

Thanks much in advance!

[Lyric Opera Website](https://www.lyricopera.org/)

[image: Lyric Opera Menus]

Comment: Note that the 7/2 rule has nothing to do with menus: http://uxmyths.com/post/931925744/myth-23-choices-should-always-be-limited-to-seven as for the questions, context is everything. We can't say 2 menus is better than one without the context of the site itself. It's always going to depend.

Comment: It's an interesting question. Could you narrow the scope of it?

Comment: Hm, not sure how you mean. I guess you could think of the question in the example that I've just given -- do the two menus work on Lyric, and if they don't what would be a better solution. You could address the opposite too, which is where this kind of solution would be advantageous and even preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer: no.

I don't have any evidence based on research, but generally speaking less is more. They have a lot of redundant links on that home page: 'Inside Lyric', 'Ryan Opera Center', and 'About' are all related and could be accessed through one link. Same goes for most of the other options.

Look at Apple.com. Every single product or service can accessed through seven links, plus the home, search, and cart link.

Comment: Ah, it's great that you brought apple.com. I was just there and you are right about the top navigation only having the 7 links. However, if you click on those links you are taken to the other sections of the site that include this same kind of double menu.

Comment: True, but the second row of navigation is based on the selection of a link on the home page and does reveal until you make a selection. Also, the second row of navigation never has redundant options.